# Crop image to bounding box in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow

How can I crop an image to the bounding box in Tensorflow? I am using the Python API.

From the documentation,

```
tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, offset_height, offset_width, target_height, target_width)
```

> Crops an image to a specified bounding box.
>
> This op cuts a rectangular part out of image. The top-left corner of the returned image is at offset_height, offset_width in image, and its lower-right corner is at offset_height + target_height, offset_width + target_width.

I can get the coordinates of a bounding box in normalized coordinates as,

```
    ymin = boxes[0,i,0]
    xmin = boxes[0,i,1]
    ymax = boxes[0,i,2]
    xmax = boxes[0,i,3]
```

and convert these to absolute coordinates,

```
    (xminn, xmaxx, yminn, ymaxx) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width, ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
```

However I cant figure out how to use these coordinates in the `crop_to_bounding_box` function.

Comment: you might like this article :) https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/infrastructure/2018/Smart-Auto-Cropping-of-Images.html?utm_content=buffer611dd&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since we consider `x` as horizontal and `y` as vertical, following would crop the image with specified box.

```
cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, yminn, xminn, 
                                       ymaxx - yminn, xmaxx - xminn)
```

Comment: @IshantMrinal: Do you happen to also know, how we can fill the inside of the bounding box with a color? suppose I want to censor some parts in the image. I noticed here : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L169
that it uses PIL draw rectangle, and it also initializes the fill argument, however it doesnt fill the rectangle with any color! 
Can you assist me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code from cropping and saving bounding box in in tensorflow

```
 for idx in range(len(bboxes)):
    if bscores[idx] >= Threshold:
      #Region of Interest
      y_min = int(bboxes[idx][0] * im_height)
      x_min = int(bboxes[idx][1] * im_width)
      y_max = int(bboxes[idx][2] * im_height)
      x_max = int(bboxes[idx][3] * im_width)

      class_label = category_index[int(bclasses[idx])]['name']
      class_labels.append(class_label)
      bbox.append([x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, class_label, float(bscores[idx])])

      #Crop Image - Working Code
      cropped_image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, y_min, x_min, y_max - y_min, x_max - x_min).numpy().astype(np.int32)

      # encode_jpeg encodes a tensor of type uint8 to string
      output_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(cropped_image)
      # decode_jpeg decodes the string tensor to a tensor of type uint8
      #output_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(output_image)

      score = bscores[idx] * 100

      file_name = tf.constant(OUTPUT_PATH+image_name[:-4]+'_'+str(idx)+'_'+class_label+'_'+str(round(score))+'%'+'_'+os.path.splitext(image_name)[1])

      writefile = tf.io.write_file(file_name, output_image)
```