# Crop image in Tensorflow Object Detection API and display it

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm using the tensorflow objection detection API to detect MRZ codes on passports. I've already trained the data and everything is working fine. It perfectly identifies the MRZ codes surrounding it with a bounding box. However, now I just want to crop the MRZ code (or the bounding box) and having trouble doing so using the PIL Image library. This is how my code looks like:

```
# Import packages
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from PIL import Image

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
IMAGE_NAME = 'test.jpg'

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'training','labelmap.pbtxt')

# Path to image
PATH_TO_IMAGE = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,IMAGE_NAME)

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 6

# Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `king`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Load image using OpenCV and
# expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
# i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
image = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
image_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})


# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    np.squeeze(boxes),
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=8,
    min_score_thresh=0.80)



width, height = image.shape[:2]
for i, box in enumerate(np.squeeze(boxes)):
      if(np.squeeze(scores)[i] > 0.80):
        (ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax) = (box[0]*height, box[1]*width, box[2]*height, box[3]*width)
        im = Image.open('test.jpg')
        im.crop((ymin, xmin, ymax - ymax, xmax - xmin)).show()

# All the results have been drawn on image. Now display the image.
cv2.imshow('Object detector', image)

# Press any key to close the image
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


However, I always get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 482, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
AttributeError: '_idat' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection_image.py", line 128, in <module>
    im.crop((ymin, xmin, ymax - ymax, xmax - xmin)).show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1977, in show
    _show(self, title=title, command=command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2802, in _show
    _showxv(image, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2807, in _showxv
    ImageShow.show(image, title, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 51, in show
    if viewer.show(image, title=title, **options):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 75, in show
    return self.show_image(image, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 95, in show_image
    return self.show_file(self.save_image(image), **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 91, in save_image
    return image._dump(format=self.get_format(image), **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 624, in _dump
    self.save(filename, format, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1930, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 821, in _save
    [("zip", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 490, in _save
    e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

I've tried changing the numbers around multiple times. Sometimes the cropped picture is just black. Tried searching for google but just can't seem to get the bounding box. I'm be very grateful for any help.

Comment: The PIL crop is usually im.crop(left, upper, right, lower) so should it be im.crop((xmin, ymin, xmin, ymax)) ?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this question i asked last year

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518357/how-to-save-the-bounding-boxes-to-disk-as-images-while-using-object-detection-ap

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is find the file in specified path models/research/object detection/utils/visualizatioin_utils.py

do following thing

```
import cv2

count = 0
```

find a funtion

```
      def draw_bounding_box_on_image():
             draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image):
             arr = np.array(image)
             im_width, im_height = image.size

 if use_normalized_coordinates:
    (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                              ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
     a,b,c,d = int(left) , int(right) , int(top) ,int(bottom)
     arr = arr[c:d,a:b]
     global count
     cv2.imwrite("yourpath/QRCODE{}.jpg".format(count),arr)
     count = count+1

 else:
    (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    draw.line([(left, top), (left, bottom), (right, bottom),
         (right, top), (left, top)], width=thickness, fill=color
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code at last of visualization_utils.py,

find the function 'visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array' 
then I appended the detected boxes into an array.

```
for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
   if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
      box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
      bigger_bounding_box.append(box)
```

I added the following code:

```
bigger_bounding_box=[]
count =0
for i in range(0,len(bigger_bounding_box)):
        im_width, im_height = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]
        arr = numpy.array(image)
        box = bigger_bounding_box[i]
        xmin  = box[0]
        ymin  = box[1]
        xmax  = box[2]
        ymax  = box[3]
        (left, right, top, bottom) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width, ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
        a,b,c,d = int(left) , int(right) , int(top) ,int(bottom)
        arr = arr[c:d,a:b]
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/tensor19/Desktop/images/QRCODE{}.jpg".format(count),arr)
        count =count+1
```

The model is able to detect the objects in the Input image but It is not cropping the same objects that were detected in the input image.

Answer (score -1):

@Rochan had almost the perfect answer to the question. I would like to point out a mistake in your code.

```
      ymin  = boxi[0]
      xmin  = boxi[1]
      ymax  = boxi[2]
      xmax  = boxi[3]
```

(this is the correct format)

Thank you so much for this @Rochan

Comment: How is this correct? there's no `boxi` in the code, only `box`